# FluentNHibernate Many-To-One References where Foreign Key is not to Primary Key and column names are different

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I've been sitting here for an hour trying to figure this out...

I've got 2 tables (abbreviated):

```
CREATE TABLE TRUST 
(
TRUSTID NUMBER NOT NULL,
ACCTNBR VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
)
CONSTRAINT TRUST_PK PRIMARY KEY (TRUSTID)

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTHISTORY
(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
ACCOUNTNUMBER VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
TRANSAMT NUMBER(38,2) NOT NULL
POSTINGDATE DATE NOT NULL
)
CONSTRAINT ACCOUNTHISTORY_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

I have 2 classes that essentially mirror these:

```
public class Trust
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }

}

public class AccountHistory
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Trust Trust {get; set;}
    public virtual DateTime PostingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal IncomeAmount { get; set; }
```

}

How do I do the many-to-one mapping in FluentNHibernate to get the AccountHistory to have a Trust?  Specifically, since it is related on a different column than the Trust primary key of TRUSTID and the column it is referencing is also named differently (ACCTNBR vs. ACCOUNTNUMBER)????  Here's what I have so far - how do I do the References on the AccountHistoryMap to Trust???

```
public class TrustMap : ClassMap<Trust>
{
    public TrustMap()
    {
        Table("TRUST");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("TRUSTID");
        Map(x => x.AccountNumber).Column("ACCTNBR");
    }
}

public class AccountHistoryMap : ClassMap<AccountHistory>
{
    public AccountHistoryMap()
    {
        Table("TRUSTACCTGHISTORY");
        Id (x=>x.Id).Column("ID");
        References<Trust>(x => x.Trust).Column("ACCOUNTNUMBER").ForeignKey("ACCTNBR").Fetch.Join();
        Map(x => x.PostingDate).Column("POSTINGDATE");
        );
```

I've tried a few different variations of the above line but can't get anything to work - it pulls back AccountHistory data and a proxy for the Trust; however it says no Trust row with given identifier.

This has to be something simple.  Anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use [property-ref](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping/1nr4enxv3dpeq/8#5%282E%291%282E%2910%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29many%282D%29to%282D%29one):

```
public class AccountHistoryMap : ClassMap<AccountHistory>
{
    public AccountHistoryMap()
    {
        Table("TRUSTACCTGHISTORY");
        Id (x=>x.Id).Column("ID");
        References(x => x.Trust, "ACCOUNTNUMBER").PropertyRef("ACCTNBR").Fetch.Join();
        Map(x => x.PostingDate).Column("POSTINGDATE");
    }
}
```