# Mapping a foreign key to something other than a primary key

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my database there are tables *Assignment* and *Workplace*, conceptually, every assignment takes place at exactly one workplace. The *Assignment* table contains a column *Workplace*, which is a foreign key referencing the *Workplace* table's *WorkplaceName* column.

This is the schema:

```
table Workplace (
  ID int primary key,
  WorkplaceName int
)

table Assignment (
  Workplace int
)
```

And my mapping:

```
class Workplace
{
  public virtual int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual int WorkplaceName { get; set; }
} 

class Assignment 
{
  public virtual Workplace { get; set; }
}

class AssignmentMap : ClassMap<Assignment>
{
  public AssignmentMap()
  {
    References(a => a.Workplace);
  }
}
```

At runtime I get the exception

> No row with the given identifier exists[MyProject.Workplace#2001]

The issue here seems to be that FH looks for the value of the *Assignment.Workplace* property in the *Workplace.ID* column, the table's primary key; the correct place would be the *Workplace.WorkplaceName* column. I have tried to use the `ForeignName` method, thinking I could specify *WorkplaceName* this way. How can I tell FH how to join the correct columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer here: [FluentNHibernate Many-To-One References where Foreign Key is not to Primary Key and column names are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890359/fluentnhibernate-many-to-one-references-where-foreign-key-is-not-to-primary-key)

The solution was to use `PropertyRef`; the line reads now:

```
References(x => x.Workplace).PropertyRef(x => x.WorkplaceName).Fetch.Join();
```

What I didn't realize was that I needed to give a reference to the client-side object's property *WorkplaceName*, instead of trying to instruct the mapping to use the server-side column *WorkplaceName*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be something like

`References(x => x.Workplace).Column("WorkplaceName")`

Comment: I've tried that; it doesn't change the outcome. I believe the `Column` method is used to specify the local column name, same as the second argument to `References` - I could be wrong on that, though.